# Can I use shared lib for static lib in c++?

Tags: android, c++, build, android-ndk

I have some confusing situations about android native build configuration like below.

Case1) and Case2) are allowed?
What are problems in this situation?

**Case 1) Using static lib for shared lib**

A module makefile:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := A

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

B module makefile:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := B

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := A 

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

**Case 2) Using shared lib for static lib**

A module makefile:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := A

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

B module makefile:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := B 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := A

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer for my questions

Comment: I would say "try it and see". I presume the linker will just say "cannot find this library". Use the CMake-based build system if you can, it is much nicer.

Comment: Why not just use [`LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk#local_shared_libraries)?